# CREATE and DROP TABLE using Zend Adapter

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db

I'm trying to do some SQL queries using Zend adapter. The code that I'm trying to use is something like this:

`$result = $this->$db->getConnection()->exec('CREATE TABLE TEST');`

and I know that $db is set and works properly, because I can run other commands such as

`$this->$db->listTables();` or

`$result = $this->$db->fetchAssoc("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " .$schema);`

As I was reading through Zend documentation, it was mentioned that some database transactions that are not prepared should be used through the first example (e.g. `exec("...")` ), but apparently I have problems running those.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This should work ...

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $db->query('CREATE TABLE wolf (tag VARCHAR(9))');
```